# Identification of unknown device with a coaxial connector

Tags: identification

I would be interested to know what this device is, if anyone can identify it?

The screw fitting at the base is just a coaxial fitting and there appears to be nothing much on the inside and no visible way of fitting anything. It's copper plated so no heat has been applied. Possibly army or air force, and I am guessing from 1950s - 1970s. It's about 150 mm long

[image: photo of device]

[image: Other side of base]

Comment: Could you post a photo looking into the "coaxial fitting" and closeups of the other protrusions around the base?

Comment: @Kevin Reid  I don't have a photo of the end but here is the other side of the base.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an isotropic radiator for W band (300GHz).

All the holes ensure there are no nulls in the radiation pattern.

Comment: Maybe, but I doubt they would use an old VHF/UHF PL-259(?) style connector (which is what appears to be on the bottom) for 300 GHz.  And also I'm not sure the W band was being much, if at all, back in those days.

Comment: More likely an N connector; still only good to 11 GHz.  W band is stated as 75-110 GHz.